# Android Studio (Kotlin) - VideoView Goes Black After Switching Apps

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-videoview

I have a very simple video playing in the bottom third of my main activity, on a loop. When the app is minimized and then I come back to it, the video will have stopped playing, displaying a black screen instead, and there seems to be no way to get it playing again. (I do not want video controls.)

Here's my MainActivity.kt:

```
import android.app.ActionBar
import android.graphics.Color
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.VideoView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

import android.widget.TextView
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable

class MainActivity :  AppCompatActivity() {

    // declaring a null variable for VideoView
    var simpleVideoView: VideoView? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
        supportActionBar?.hide()

        // assigning id of VideoView from
        // activity_main.xml layout file
        simpleVideoView = findViewById<View>(R.id.videoView) as VideoView

        // set the absolute path of the video file which is going to be played
        simpleVideoView!!.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                + packageName + "/" + R.raw.gp))

        simpleVideoView!!.requestFocus()

        // starting the video
        simpleVideoView!!.start()

        simpleVideoView!!.setOnCompletionListener { simpleVideoView!!.start() }

    }

}
```

Comment: See documentation: "VideoView does not retain its full state when going into the background. In particular, it does not restore the current play state, play position, selected tracks, or any subtitle tracks added via addSubtitleSource(). Applications should save and restore these on their own in Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) and Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)."

Comment: @Cristi Thank you for your answer. I'm a complete newb to Android and Kotlin and amateur at best with coding in general. Can you please elaborate on where to put the code you're referring to? (This is just a tiny little app for my own personal use, so it doesn't have to be perfect.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be:

class MainActivity :  AppCompatActivity() {

```
    var simpleVideoView: VideoView? = null
    var currentPosition = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
        supportActionBar?.hide()

    
        simpleVideoView = findViewById<View>(R.id.videoView) as VideoView

        
        simpleVideoView!!.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://"
            + packageName + "/" + R.raw.gp))

        simpleVideoView!!.setOnCompletionListener {     simpleVideoView!!.start() }

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        var position = savedInstanceState.getInt("position")
        simpleVideoView!!.seekTo(position)
    }

}

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        if (currentPosition != 0)
             simpleVideoView!!.seekTo(currentPosition)

        simpleVideoView!!.start()

    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (!simpleVideoView!!.isPlaying) {
            if (currentPosition != 0)
                simpleVideoView!!.seekTo(currentPosition)

            simpleVideoView!!.start()
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        simpleVideoView!!.pause()
        currentPosition = simpleVideoView!!.currentPosition
    }

    override fun onStop() {
         simpleVideoView!!.pause()
         super.onStop()
     }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        outState.putInt("position", currentPosition)
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }
```

}

This restarts the video at the same point where it left when rotating the device. You might want to check out the exoplayer from android instead of the VideoView.

Comment: This resolved my issue. Thank you so much!